# Splitting a WebClient Post of a Streaming Flux into JSON Arrays

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I am using a third-party REST controller which accepts an array of JSON objects and returns a single object response. When I POST from a WebClient using a limited `Flux` the code works (I assume, because the `Flux` completes).

However, when the `Flux` is potentially unlimited, how do I;

1. POST in chunks of arrays?
2. Capture the response, per POSTed array?
3. Stop the transmission of the `Flux`?

Here is my bean;

```
public class Car implements Serializable {

    Long id;

    public Car() {}
    public Car(Long id) { this.id = id; }
    public Long getId() {return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
}
```

This is how I assume that the third-party client looks like;

```
@RestController
public class ThirdPartyServer {

    @PostMapping("/cars")
    public CarResponse doCars(@RequestBody List<Car> cars) {
        System.err.println("Got " + cars);
        return new CarResponse("OK");
    }
}
```

And here is my code. When I POST `flux2` , on completion a JSON array is sent. However, when I POST `flux1`, nothing is sent after the first `take(5)`. How do POST the next chunks of 5?

```
@Component
public class MyCarClient {

    public void sendCars() {

//      Flux<Car> flux1 = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(250)).map(i -> new Car(i));
        Flux<Car> flux2 = Flux.range(1, 10).map(i -> new Car((long) i));

        WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");
        client
            .post()
            .uri("/cars")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(flux2, Car.class) 
//          .body(flux1.take(5).collectList(), new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Car>>() {})
            .exchange()
            .subscribe(r -> System.err.println(r.statusCode()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. How do I POST in chunks of arrays?

Use one of the variants of [`Flux.window`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#window-int-) to split the main flux into windowed fluxes, and then send the requests using the windowed fluxes via `.flatMap`

```java
        Flux<Car> flux1 = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(250)).map(i -> new Car(i));

        WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");
        Disposable disposable = flux1
                // 1
                .window(5)
                .flatMap(windowedFlux -> client
                        .post()
                        .uri("/cars")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .body(windowedFlux, Car.class)
                        .exchange()
                        // 2
                        .doOnNext(response -> System.out.println(response.statusCode()))
                        .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(...)))
                .subscribe();

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        // 3
        disposable.dispose();
```

> 2. How do I capture the response, per POSTed array?

You can analyze the response via operators after `.exchange()`.

In the example I provided, the response can be seen in the `doOnNext` operator, but you can use any operator that operates on `onNext` signals, such as `map` or `handle`.

Be sure to read the response body fully to ensure the connection is returned back to the pool (see [note](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-exchange)).  Here, I have used `.bodyToMono`, but any `.body` or `.toEntity` method will work.

> 3. Stop the transmission of the Flux?

When using the `subscribe` method as you have done, you can stop the flow using the returned `disposable.dispose()`.

Alternatively, you can return the Flux from the `sendCars()` method and delegate the subscription and disposing to the caller.

Note that in the example I provided, I just used `Thread.sleep()` to simulate waiting.  In a real application, you should use something more advanced, and avoid `Thread.sleep()`

Comment: 2nd time in two weeks that you have come to my rescue! I have a rather open ended question for you; How did you arrive at this answer? I have read the `Flux` and `WebClient` API documents many times as well as Googling for many examples, but I never got close to using the `WebClient` **within** the `flatMap`. I was assuming that all the `Flux` magic of breaking the stream into arrays would happen in the `.body()` method !

Comment: Glad I could help!  The `WebClient` `exchange()` method only represents a single request.  And in order to identify the "end" of the JSON array to send in that request, the `body(...)` reads the `Flux` given to it fully (meaning it must complete before the request is completed).  Therefore, I realized that the input `Flux` needed to be broken up into chucks (one chunk per request).  And one way to break up a `Flux` into chunks is the `window(...)` methods.

Comment: thanks, that should go to help me solve future problems.

Comment: Phil, you may want to amend the answer. When running the solution, the posting stops after a few iterations, because the response payload is not being read and the http connection is not being released, thus emptying the pool. You need to flatMap() after the exchange(). See the comment at the end of section 2.3 https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-exchange

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer to show one possible way (out of many) of reading the response.