# Detecting an empty Flux Window before Webclient Post

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams

With reference to my previous question [Splitting a WebClient Post of a Streaming Flux into JSON Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55523944/splitting-a-webclient-post-of-a-streaming-flux-into-json-arrays) , I was using;

```
myFlux
 .window(5)
 .flatMap(window -> client
  .post()
  .body(window, myClass.class)
  .exchange()
  .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono)
 )
 .subscribe();
```

This works fine. However, on a slow day, 5 messages make take a while to arrive and the `window` will not send anything until the `window` is full. So
I switched to `windowTimeout(5, Duration.ofSeconds(5))`.

Now, if there is no data and the `Duration` is exceeded, the code is propagating an empty `window` which is causing an empty array to be posted.

How do I detect an empty `window` and not run the `post`?

Comment: can you do a `window.map(value -> client.post()...syncBody(value))`?
This would look into the window Flux, and if nothing is there, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to know how many items will be emitted by a Flux without reading the entire Flux to completion.

Since your window size is relatively small, you could collect all the items emitted by the Flux into a `List` using `.collectList()`, and then check to see if the list is empty before sending the request.

```java
myFlux
    .windowTimeout(5, Duration.ofSeconds(5))
    .flatMap(window ->
        // collect everything in the window into a list
        window.collectList()
             // ignore empty windows
            .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
             // send the request
            .flatMap(list -> client
                .post()
                .body(Flux.fromIterable(list), MyClass.class)
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(MyResponse.class))))
```

Comment: @ Phil to the rescue again! The change played havoc with my editor, so I broke it down into `filteredFlux = myFlux.windowTimeout().flatMap(w.collectList().filter())` then `filterFlux.flatMap(list -> client.post())`